# How to delete a specific characters using python in notepad rt++

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

so i have been using a program from github that allows me autotype in notepad rt ++ but there is a issue that in every word the notepad rt++ adds "4" in between.

So can you help me with a (Python) program that automatically deletes the number "4" from the sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi You can use regex to change any string in Python.

First import the re library:

```
import re
```

Then you can use the sub function to change any string or any text file or even scraping..

for example:

```
str = "This is a simple test 4 regex"
str_change = re.sub(r'4 ', '', str)
print(str_change)
```

output:

```
This is a simple test regex
```